# How to send Log4Net logs to Application Insights for .NET Core 3.1 web application?

Tags: .net-core, log4net, azure-application-insights, .net-core-3.1, log4net-appender

Not able to flush Log4Net logs to azure application insights in the web app for net core 3.1

Here're the project files.

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
        <!--Application Insights Appender-->
        <appender name='aiAppender' 
        type='Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, 
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender'>
        <layout type='log4net.Layout.PatternLayout'>
        <conversionPattern value='%message%newline' />
        </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
        </root>
</log4net>
```

**ApplicationInsights.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey>..Added InstrumentationKey here..</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }
```

**Nuget Packages:**

[image]

**appsettings.json**

```
{
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "<Added instrumentation key here>"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "ApplicationInsights": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Error"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I got this working finally by updating ConfigureServices() in Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
        {
            InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"],
            EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true
        });
    }
```